# Limit of a function with rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1-x & if x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
x & if x\not\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
Determine $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ if it exists.

How do I approach this question? It seems obvious that it doesn't exist but when $x$ is zero, $x$ is a rational number since $0$ is. But when $x$ is a tiny bit smaller than $0$,  it is irrational. So how do I show the limits are not equal if I can not use both equations in $f$ since $0$ is rational?

Comment: The function is continuous in $\dfrac12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subsequences $f(x_n)_{x_n \in \mathbb Q}$ and $f(x_k)_{x_k \in \mathbb R -\mathbb Q}$ Obviously $$f(x_n)\to 1 \qquad \text { but } \qquad  f(x_k)\to 0$$ thus the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

If $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=A$ , then for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges $x$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=A$.

Can you use the above claim to prove the limit does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{n} \quad\text{and}\quad y_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}.
$$
Then $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb Q$ and $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ and
$$
x_n\to 0,\quad y_n\to 0.
$$
Hence
$$
f(x_n)=1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1 \quad\text{and}\quad f(y_n)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\to 0,
$$
and therefore $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: are you not meant to mention that the x_n andy_n both converge to zero as n tends to infinity?

Comment: Yes. I have corrected now my answer.

Comment: but do you not consider now when x tends to zero? cuz for your f(x_n) and f(y_n) you've considered it when n goes to infinity. I thought you'd have to consider when n goes to zero since the question had x going to zero?

Comment: $n\to\infty$ but $x_n,y_n\to 0$, and that's what matters.

Comment: so u just forget about the original destination of x?

Comment: Both sequence tend to 0, and the sequences of their images tend to different limit. Hence $f$ is discontinuous. I do not understand what exactly you do not understand.

Comment: hey would it still be correct if you put {x_n} is an element of Q and {y_n} is not an element of Q, instead of the strict subset thing?